# Rails controller design help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this scenario.

My Models

```
class User
end

class Student 
  has_many :daily_records
end

class DailyRecords
  belongs_to :student
end
```

### What i am trying to archive

1. i want to create a form on the student's show page to enter data for his daily records.
2. i want the form to have the id for the user entering the data. 
   How can i design the controller for this scenario.

### What i have done so far.

1. i added the user model using Devise
2. i have scaffold the two model (student, daily_record) and added the associations as seen above.

I know i need to work on the show action of the student controller to make this work. I need help. just new to rails
thanks

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_student
  def show
    <--help code--->
  end
........
```

Comment: `@student ||= Student.includes(:daily_records).find(params[:id)`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. But what I need to to create a form in the show page. Which will enable me to entries  for the daily records

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html . And then you can check out gems like https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon for nested associations

Comment: @foliwe83 students are also users right?

Comment: @RafayetMonon .No The Users are like teachers. So Basically they will enter data for students. The entry will be associated to the student  but need know the User who did the entry .

Comment: @foliwe83 are there going to be multiple record entries in one form for a student?

Comment: @Rafayet Monon . Yes there is a day , time and notes  entries . I can always add more